# Upsizing of tyre to 205/50r15 where actual rim size is 14"

Tags: tires, wheels

Can I use a 15" alloy with 205/50r15 tyre in maruti suzuki ritz where the actual rim size of the car is 14"?

Comment: There are many tire company sites that will show you the equivalent rollimg radius, search for tire size comparison

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Are you wanting to use a 15" rim with the tire you have specified in place of the current 14" rim? Your question isn't quite clear on this, so thought I'd ask.

Comment: Duplicate of : https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/q/52451/10976

Answer (score 2):

Short answer; maybe. It might work if certain details are met, of which you did not provide.

First, the bolt pattern and center hole must be correct for the rim to mount safely (5.5Jx14 ET45).

Second, the mounted tire must fit in the wheel wells without interference. The 205/50R15 is close to the size of the stock tires listed on the internet that I could find (165/80R14 or 185/70R14 on 2009 to 2019 models).

**YOU** will have to determine if they will fit properly and the steering swing clears all suspension and body components.

Answer (score 0):

In short, no.

The R15 part of the tyre designation means that the tyres have been manufactured with rim beads of 15" diameter.  A 14" wheel will slip through the middle of an R15 tyre so there would be no way to mount the tyre.

Comment: If you read the question again, I believe the OP is asking if they can use 15" wheels and tires in place of the 14" ones.

Comment: My apologies, I'd read it as 15R tyres on 14" steel wheels.  My response only applies if the intention is to retain the 14" steel wheels.  In order to answer the different ratio question, more info would be needed.  Primarily the size of the existing tyres.

Comment: Actually I got the vehicle with 165/80R14 rim wheel and I upsized it to 185/70R14. I just wanted to know if 205/50R15 with 15" alloy wheel (instead of 14" rim wheel) suits my vehicle and about.the advantages and disadvantages of using it.